# Song played at Noragami Aragoto episode 12 19:00

Tags: music, noragami

What is the name of soundtrack used in *Noragami Aragoto* episode 12 @ 19:00 when Yato cuts Pacification ring?

Answer (score 1):

It's the 11th song on the Noragami Aragoto soundtrack Footsteps. The portion we hear during that scene starts at minute 1:17 and crescendos around 2:00 when Yato uses Sekki.